# full <-> full-desktop without reinstalling

Tags: ros, ubuntu, pandaboard, ubuntu-natty, desktop-full

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
I am working the a Natty 10.04 ubuntu on a PANDABOARD.
I had trouble installing the desktop-full version and installed the full version instead

Now I see there are a LOT of stacks missing and as I understand - navigation (SLAM?) packages will be missing as well?

I do not want to go over the installation again

1. can I manually install missing stacks that exist in the "desktop-full" and not in the "full"?
2. is that the only difference between the two - missing stacks?
   thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12795/full-%3C-%3E-full-desktop-without-reinstalling/) by [shachar](https://answers.ros.org/users/1708/shachar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-01-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It sounds like you are installing from the Natty Ubuntu Debian package repository.

Yes, you should be able to install additional missing stacks without affecting those you already have. Each Debian package contains a ROS stack.

Electric variants are defined in [REP 113](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0113.html)  Diamondback in [REP 108](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0108.html)

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-01-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0